# Why does my app built through Bazel crash after adding Firebase dependencies as soon as it is opened?

Tags: java, android, bazel

```
2019-01-28 14:41:46.839 30612-30612/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sensennetworks.senanpr, PID: 30612
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incorrect provider authority in manifest. Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6717)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7018)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:514)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:837)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incorrect provider authority in manifest. Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle.
```

I am getting this crash as soon as I open it. Here's my WORKSPACE file,

```
aar_import_external(
      name = 'com_google_firebase_firebase_messaging_directboot_17_0_3',
      licenses = ['notice'], # apache
      aar_urls = ['https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging-directboot/17.0.3/firebase-messaging-directboot-17.0.3.aar'],
      aar_sha256 = '',
      deps = [
        '@com_google_android_gms_play_services_basement_16_0_1//aar',
        '@com_google_android_gms_play_services_tasks_16_0_1//aar',
        '@com_google_firebase_firebase_common_16_0_3//aar',
        '@com_google_firebase_firebase_iid_17_0_4//aar',
        '@com_google_firebase_firebase_messaging_17_3_4//aar',
        '@com_google_android_gms_play_services_stats_16_0_1//aar',
        '@com_google_firebase_firebase_iid_interop_16_0_1//aar',
      ],
    )
```

I am importing the same in BUILD file.

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incorrect provider authority in manifest. Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle.`

Comment: Have you integrated google-services.json properly? https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/master/android/firebase-cloud-messaging / https://github.com/bazelbuild/tools_android

Comment: @Jin Thanks it worked, I was integrating google-services.json wrong.

Comment: @sonudelhikkc great! I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to integrate `google-services.json` using the tooling in [bazelbuild/tools_android](https://github.com/bazelbuild/tools_android). Android builds require post-processing the JSON file which is generated into a resource XML.